# Why <p> tag acts as a block element and inline element interchangeably

Tags: javascript, html

In the following code snippet using `JavaScript`, a `button` element is created and added to the dom as a child of a `p` tag. However, while the `p` tag is a block element, for some reason, the `button` element is displayed alongside the `p` tag's contents. Why doesn't it go to the next line? Here is the code I am currently using:

```
const generateNoteDOM = function(note) {
    const noteEl = document.createElement('p');

    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.textContent = 'x';

    if (note.title.length > 0) {
        noteEl.textContent = note.title;
    } else {
        noteEl.textContent = 'Unnamed note';
    }
    noteEl.appendChild(button);
    return noteEl;
};
```

[This is how it appears.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUObr.png)

Comment: It isb by default a block level element. However, what you think p is not p but the TEXT NODE of p.

Comment: You're appending text and a button *within* the paragraph. Essentially `<p>Unnamed note<button>x</button><p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this happens is that you've made your button... called `button` a child of your `p` element `noteE1`, and as such it appears "inline" while it is simply the result of [nesting](https://www.lifewire.com/nesting-html-tags-3466475) the elements.

You can fix this by adding a wrapper element as follows.

```
const generateNoteDOM = function(note) {
    const wrapper = document.createElement('div'); // All the content will go inside this element.
    const noteEl = document.createElement('p');

    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.textContent = 'x';

    if (note.title.length > 0) {
        noteEl.textContent = note.title;
    } else {
        noteEl.textContent = 'Unnamed note';
    }
    wrapper.appendChild(p)
    wrapper.appendChild(button);

    return wrapper
};
```

This will result in a dom looking like this:

```html
<div>
  <p>Unnamed note</p>
  <button>x</button>
</div>
```

The reason it works this way is a basic concept in HTML; children elements generally are placed inside their parents. The p tag is still inline, but it won't force the button onto a new line because it's *meant* to be contained inside it. If you add a third element into the wrapper, you'll see that it won't go on the same line as the p tag. There are many [other resources](https://lorelle.wordpress.com/2015/04/19/wordpress-school-html-and-css-parent-child-relationship/) on this, and a multitude of exceptions to everything I've said, but this contains the basics.

Answer (score 1):

A p element is by default a block level element. What you think p is not p but its `text node`, bacause you just did that by setting `textContent`. The button is by default `inline-block` and therefore places itself right next to the text node. The bounding client rectangle of the p is therefore the textNode + button itself.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the `<button>` element is inside the `<p>` element:

```html
<p>some text <button></button></p>
```

But the `<p>` is actually a block element:

```html
<p>some text</p><button></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It being block-level doesn't change the behavior of its content. Naturally, inline items within the `p` are still inline.

Also, post HTML. The JavaScript doesn't have anything to do with the flow.

Comment: you are impressive, just 3 hours to get to 46 rep, took me a few months

Comment: @awesomeguy: Thanks... just one more vote, and they'll let me comment. ;-)